# Rest framework serializer read only

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to validate if value was changed by user from read only field. If value was changed validation should return error message. In my case start_date is always constants (read from database). I want to check if user modified this value.

Serializer:

```
class IntervalSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    start_date = serializers.DateField(allow_null=False, input_formats=INPUT_FORMATS_DATE)
    end_date = serializers.DateField(allow_null=False, input_formats=INPUT_FORMATS_DATE)
```

My view:

```
START_DATE = get_start_date()
serializer = IntervalSerializer(data=data)
if serializer.is_valid():
    ...
```

**update**

When I set read_only to True I don't have any validation errors. I want check if user changed this field. Something like:

```
START_DATE = get_start_date() # from db
data['start_date'] = get_not_allowed() #when user send date i.e. in curl
serializer = IntervalSerializer(data=data, initial={'start_date': START_DATE})
if serializer.is_valid(): #should not pass because data['start_date'] is overriden
```

IntervalSerializer(data=data)

Answer (score 3):

How about just setting **read_only** to True ?
See [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#core-arguments)

So, basically, you would have:

```
start_date = serializers.DateField(read_only=True, allow_null=False, input_formats=INPUT_FORMATS_DATE)
```

Comment: Validation pass but I have not any errors when user change field read_only

Comment: @user3455448 you can raise an Exception inside the `update` method of the serializer if the data-supplied start_date doesn't match the old one.